# When creating a mapping table with two foreign keys, how does one create a foreign key constraint?

Tags: mariadb

I'm using MariaDB and have 2 tables I'm trying to map together into another table. I've done foreign key relationships before, but never with a primary key from two tables. How do I go about creating the constraint?

Table 1:

```
Order_ID (Primary Key)
Order_Amount
```

Table 2:

```
Customer_ID (Primary Key)
Customer_Name
```

Table 3: Mapping Table

```
Order_ID
Customer_ID

Primary Key (Order_ID & Customer_ID)
```

When the customer table row is deleted, I want the map to be deleted to that order, but not the order table row.

Would something like this work?

```
ALTER TABLE `map_table` ADD CONSTRAINT `fk_customer_id` FOREIGN KEY (`customer_id`) REFERENCES `customers`(`customer_id`) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE;
```

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.3&fiddle=41fb379c852502e976211aebaaad36ad

Comment: Do you really have multiple Customers associated with a single Order?  If not, you should not use the extra table.

Comment: @RickJames It was more of an example. Table names were used to simplify the question.

Comment: A `FOREIGN KEY` is a combination of a `CONSTRAINT` and an `INDEX`.